# How to use the response of Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I make an ajax POST request to post JSON data to server, and I get a simple text response. I can see that everything works fine because it is shown in the browser's  debugger. However, I cannot use it.

```
    callajax1(Callback);


    function callajax1(callbackfn) {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Data: data }),
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data2) {
            callbackfn(data2);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {

        }
    });
    return false;
}


function Callback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

No alert is showing.

Comment: how do you call "callajax1" ?

Comment: `callajax1(Callback);`

Comment: some console errors? 
in $.Ajax() use `error` instead `failure`... see the code response in console.

Comment: is "success" actually fired?

Comment: You call `callajax1(Callback);` before define it... you are in domready? in other case you place `callajax1(Callback);` after it's defines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you are getting a "simple text response" back, but your JavaScript (`dataType: "json"`) says to ignore the content type of the response and parse it as JSON.

Perhaps (since you are sending JSON and claiming it is plain text) you are confusing `dataType` (override the content type the server returns) and `contentType` (describe the data you are sending).

If the response is "simple text" and not JSON then you can't parse it as JSON. Either return JSON or use `dataType: 'text'`.

Comment: Thank you for making clear the difference between `contentType` and `dataType`. This solved the problem. `dataType:'text'` works while `dataType:'text/plain; charset=utf-8'` doesn't. Why does that happen?

Comment: with dataType u define the expected response from the server. since your server-response was plain text i assume your "success" callback has never been called, but failure. see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information

Comment: @enb081 — Because the authors of jQuery wrote it like that.

Answer (score 1):

- if result of ajax is text, datatype should be text
- if result of ajax is html, datatype should be html
- if result of ajax is json, datatype should be json
- if result of ajax is xml, datatype should be xml

dataType tell jQuery to parse result in given dataType, default is 'text', though jQuery is intelligent enough to detect which conversion is required.

Comment: Which "it" are you talking about?

Comment: sorry , i go with flow

Comment: The default for jQuery is *not* text, it is "Intelligent Guess" which means "Infer it from the MIME type (`Content-Type`) of the response".

Comment: yes, if none is defined then jQuery use Intelligent Guess from MIME type of response, if anything else is there, it will be shown as simple plain text, so i can say that if intelligence is unable to find dataType, ajax will put result as plain text by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the answer here:

http://jsfiddle.net/justtal/x9re9/

```
function callajax1(callbackfn) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos',
        /*data: JSON.stringify({ Data: data }),*/
        /*contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",*/
        /*dataType: "json",*/
        success: function (data2) {
            callbackfn(data2);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            callbackfn(errMsg);
        }
    });
    return false;
}


var Callback = function (data) {
    alert(data);
}

callajax1(Callback);
```